# error de sangria en LaTeX

Tags: latex

tengo un error con las sangrías en latex, por alguna razón, luego de un lorem o blindtext latex no pone las sangrias automaticamente

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{prueba}
\author{autor}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introducción}
\blindtext \\
asdf asfsrf adsf re 

\end{document}
```

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Fue útil la respuesta? Comenta si necesitas más :)

Answer (score 0):

Se debe insertar una línea vacía entre `blindtest` y el siguiente párrafo:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{prueba}
\author{autor}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introducción}
\blindtext \\ % línea vacía debajo de esto

asdf asfsrf adsf re 

\end{document}
```

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)